# FileReader will only read small files, otherwise returning null

Tags: javascript

So I'm currently using the following code to read a file as base64:

```
function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        fr.onload = resolve(fr);
  });
}
```

Now whenever I load in a file above a certain size (unsure of what it is), it returns null for `fr.result`.

This doesn't seem to be an issue in Google Chrome, though. It will return base64 for any file size. I'm currently testing it with Microsoft Edge.

Comment: why do you need it as base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve(fr)` is being evaluated synchronously and should be wrapped in a function. You are still seeing a little bit of data because `readAsDataURL` is running asynchronously and has already managed to read some data before `resolve(fr)` is called.

You should probably register the handler before starting to read the files too.

```
function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function() { resolve(fr); };
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```